# Testing for exception thrown in several lines

Tags: junit4

I would like to test a method, in JUnit4, that does not pass at the first caught exception, but if all calls to the tested method throw exception. And I would like to know if this is possible.

I explain : let us say I have the method

```
public void setFromFen(String fenValue) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

in a class Position.

In PositionTest Junit4 class, I would like to do something like this :

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class){
    ...
    setFromFen("2"); // throws IllegalArgumentException
    setFromFen("8/8/8/8/8/8/8/8"); // does not throw IllegalArgumentException
    ...
}
```

so that the test only succeed if all calls to setFromFen fail.

In this case, though the second test does not throw IllegalArgumentException, the test succeed : and that's not what I want.

Is is it possible to get success only if all tests lines throws IllegalArgumentException ?

Comment: It looks like you are testing two different things here, surely you want to test both scenarios in separate tests, that way you can assert it has failed for that specific method call. I would recommend that approach over counting exceptions.

Comment: No I really need to have one test for all, as it is for checking if several inputs for a same method are invalids. It would be more pain for the same goal.

Comment: When you add more conditions to that test it becomes harder to maintain and you lose benefits of having unit tests report back specific errors as you don't know where the error has happened and which conditions.
Breaking out into seperate tests results in
    @Test(expected =IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testExceptionWhenArgumentLengthIsLongerThanX

rather than

public void testExceptionThrownForAVarietyOfStates

Comment: I had nine string tests, and splitting the test into methods would produce 9 methods for a similar test. After, I agree with you for the fact that i can't know where the error came from.

Comment: Also, I can store all failures in a ArrayList, and then showing content of this ArrayList.

Comment: Using exceptions to guide logic flow even in tests isn't really best practice, personally I see no problem with 9 separate tests if there are actually 9 conditions in which your logic can fail.  Just friendly advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is outside of the possibilities of the annotation.
You'll probably need something along these lines:

```
@Test
public void thatAllCallsFail() {
    int failureCount = 0;
    try {
        setFromFen(this.sampleString1);
    }
    catch( final Exception e ) {
        failureCount++;
    }
    try {
        setFromFen(this.sampleString1);
    }
    catch( final Exception e ) {
        failureCount++;
        assertEquals("All 2 calls should have failed", failureCount, 2);
    }
}
```

I'm not for a second suggesting that that is a nice way of doing it.

If you're looking for a more generic solution, perhaps adding your strings to a collection and looping over them...

```
@Test
public void thatAllCallsFail2() {
    final String[] strings = new String[] { sampleString1, sampleString2 };
    int failureCount = 0;

    for (final String string : strings) {
        try {
            setFromFen(string);
        }
        catch( final Exception e ) {
            failureCount++;
        }
    }

    assertEquals("All " + strings.length + " calls should have failed", failureCount, strings.length);
}
```

Of course, neither of these solutions will tell you which call did not throw an exception if the tests were to fail.

Comment: Thank you. I did not thought about counting exceptions throwings.